# Broadcasting message every second using websokets-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I'm building an app for receiving some info every second using websockets-rails gem. 
Right now, it seems like all messages are send after method is fully executed.

My websockets controller:

```
class DbTestsController< WebsocketRails::BaseController

  def run_tests_on_all
    dbtsch = DbTestsScheduler.new
    dbtsch.run(1, 10, message['shard'], :push) do |ops|
      send_message 'db_test.run_tests_on_all', ops
      Rails.logger.info(ops)
    end
  end

end
```

'run' method looks like

```
def run(ecfs, fafs, shard, operation)
    st = tep_t = Time.now
    while st + fafs.second > Time.now
      Octopus.using(shard) do
        send(operation)
      end
      if tep_t + ecfs.second <= Time.now
        tep_t = tep_t + 1.second
        yield(@ops) if block_given?
        @ops = 0
      end
    end
  end
```

In console I see `Rails.logger.info(ops)` outputs message every second, but `send_message` sends all 10 results at once when method execution is completed.

Comment: Upvotes mean not many people know the answer &, like me, would love to see what people come back with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is use a a gem like [sync](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync)

Real-time partials with Rails. Sync lets you render partials for models that, with minimal code, update in realtime in the browser when changes occur on the server.

you can check out a example [here](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync_example)